# Grails send emails about framework exceptions

Tags: grails, groovy, exception, log4j

In my grails app I send emails about exceptions. In my `UrlMappings.groovy`.

```
"500"(controller: "error", action: "internalError")
```

And inside my `internalError()` method in `ErrorController.groovy` I use `MailService.groovy` and send the exception details.

Now I want to send similar emails for exceptions occurred at plugins/framework eg: hibernate, GORM, grails, etc

But the problem is most of them already handled via `try catch` blocks and logged inside the plugins. For example :

```
catch(Exception e){
    log.error("Error creating workbook", e)
}
```

Is there anyway that I can email such exceptions?

Here is my log4j configurations.

```
log4j.main = {
   error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
          'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
          'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
          'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
          'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
          'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
          'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
          'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
          'org.springframework',
          'org.hibernate',
          'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I would use the [SMTPAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#SMTPAppender) to email those exceptions.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using SMTPAppender, but with no success. I tried with this one [http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=329](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=329). But it gives me runtime error `ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress` Resolved all dependencies and still no luck.